# Fix page-break-before behavior difference between IE9 and Firefox (3.6)

Tags: html, css, firefox, page-break

I'm formatting one of my webpages for printing, and in doing so am adding a pagebreak using this CSS Style.

```
@media print
{
  .page-break  { display:block; page-break-before:always; }
  .print-hidden { display:none; }
}
```

In my initial testing (printing using XPS Document Writer), I've noticed that when printing from IE9 the page breaks appear and in Firefox they do not.

A sample page output would look like :

```
<table>
    <tr class="print-hidden"><th colspan=3>Balance</th></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td><td>x</td><td>(St) Legs Together: Head Turn</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>x</td><td>(St) One Leg: </td></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="print-hidden"><th colspan=3>UE Strengthening</th></tr>
    <tr><td>100</td><td>x</td><td>(Su) Biceps</td></tr>
    <tr class="page-break"></tr>
    <tr><td>50</td><td>x</td><td>(Su) Tricpes</td></tr>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Apparently on the w3schools page for [page-break-before](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp) it says

> **Note:** Use the page-breaking properties as few times as possible and avoid page-breaking properties inside tables, floating elements,
>   and block elements with borders.

So, I guess my question(s) would be:

1. Is there a workaround for FireFox?
2. If not, how would I have to structure my html to be able to use page-break-before (or really any page breaking).

Comment: You reference W3Schools above as the W3C but W3Schools is in no way associated with the W3C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with (tested on IE9 and FF 3.6).  It behaves as I expected.

```
<ul>
    <li><reps>10</reps> x <exercisename>(St) Legs Together: Head Turn</exercisename></li> 
    <li><reps>5</reps> x <exercisename>(St) One Leg: </exercisename></li> 
    <li><reps>100</reps> x <exercisename>(Su) Biceps</exercisename></li> 
    <li class="page-break"><reps>50</reps> x <exercisename>(Su) Tricpes</exercisename></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely due to having your page-break-before class on a tr element.  Try changing to this:

```
<table>
    <tr class="print-hidden"><th colspan=3>Balance</th></tr>
    <tr><td>10</td><td>x</td><td>(St) Legs Together: Head Turn</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>x</td><td>(St) One Leg: </td></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="print-hidden"><th colspan=3>UE Strengthening</th></tr>
    <tr><td>100</td><td>x</td><td>(Su) Biceps</td></tr>
</table>
<div  class="page-break"></div>
<table>
    <tr><td>50</td><td>x</td><td>(Su) Tricpes</td></tr>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

divs are more reliable for this sort of thing.

Comment: This is leaving a blank first page and showing all 4 items on the second page, in both IE and FF.

Comment: Ah, it could be that the browser doesn't like breaking up the table across pages.  In that case, end the table, add the div, then start the table again.  I'll update by answer to show it.